# SAS how groupformat works

Tags: merge, sas

I found this on SAS official website.

`Use the GROUPFORMAT option in the BY statement to ensure that
 1. formatted values are used to group observations when a FORMAT statement and a BY statement are used together in a DATA step
 2. the FIRST.variable and LAST.variable are assigned by the formatted values of the variable`

And the example it uses to illustrate the usage of `groupformat` is

```
proc format;
   value range
      low -55 = 'Under 55'
      55-60   = '55 to 60'
      60-65   = '60 to 65'
      65-70   = '65 to 70'
      other   = 'Over 70';
run;

proc sort data=class out=sorted_class;
   by height;
run;

data _null_;
   format height range.;
   set sorted_class;
      by height groupformat;
   if first.height then
      put 'Shortest in ' height 'measures ' height:best12.;
run;
```

But I don't understand how this example shows `groupformat` "ensures" 
`formatted values are used to group observations when a FORMAT statement and a BY statement are used together in a DATA step`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the results with and without the `groupformat` statement:

```
4805
4806   data _null_;
4807      format height range.;
4808      set sorted_class;
4809         by height groupformat;
4810      if first.height then
4811         put 'Shortest in ' height 'measures ' height:best12.;
4812   run;

Shortest in Under 55 measures 51.3
Shortest in 55 to 60 measures 56.3
Shortest in 60 to 65 measures 62.5
Shortest in 65 to 70 measures 65.3
Shortest in Over 70 measures 72
NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set WORK.SORTED_CLASS.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.05 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


4813
4814   data _null_;
4815      format height range.;
4816      set sorted_class;
4817         by height ;
4818      if first.height then
4819         put 'Shortest in ' height 'measures ' height:best12.;
4820   run;

Shortest in Under 55 measures 51.3
Shortest in 55 to 60 measures 56.3
Shortest in 55 to 60 measures 56.5
Shortest in 55 to 60 measures 57.3
Shortest in 55 to 60 measures 57.5
Shortest in 55 to 60 measures 59
Shortest in 55 to 60 measures 59.8
Shortest in 60 to 65 measures 62.5
Shortest in 60 to 65 measures 62.8
Shortest in 60 to 65 measures 63.5
Shortest in 60 to 65 measures 64.3
Shortest in 60 to 65 measures 64.8
Shortest in 65 to 70 measures 65.3
Shortest in 65 to 70 measures 66.5
Shortest in 65 to 70 measures 67
Shortest in 65 to 70 measures 69
Shortest in Over 70 measures 72
NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set WORK.SORTED_CLASS.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

From there is it obvious that the `GROUPFORMAT` makes the by groups based on the FORMATTED value.  Without it, you are using the RAW value in HEIGHT.

Comment: That's very helpful. I should run the program w/ and w/o `groupformat` first. And the differences in the outputs speak for it.